# What hash function "hacks" do you use?

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

Hash function can be dependent on data. For example (from [this](https://intelligentjava.wordpress.com/2016/10/19/introduction-to-hash-tables/) article) if your data are all strings and almost all of them are of different lengths then a simple string length could be a very good hash function (not very realistic I know). Or for example real numbers from 0 to 1 could have a simple hash function:

> value * sizeOfHashTable

I am interested if you use such hash functions that are tailor made around your inputs? Any more examples?

Comment: Those types of "hacks" aren't generally useful. They work in special cases, but in the general case they suffer from one problem or another. Your real numbers case, for example, can be terrible when the range of input values is very small. Because many numbers will resolve to the same hash value. I voted to close this as too broad.

Comment: Real numbers example would have a problem if inputs are not uniformly distributed it would be fine for random inputs. Range already defined - 0 to 1. The only reason to use such "hacks" would be speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noted, hash function depends on hashed data.
Common idea to design a good hash function - to comply 3 conditions:

- Function must be easy to compute. Maybe, better to use not very good hash, but compute it quick, and save more time on hashing, than lost on imbalanced buckets or table paths.
- Function must have good distribution (pseudorandom) on test dataset. Good idea - to use in the hash function "snow-crash effect", when changing a single bit in the input data changes ~half bits in the output value.
- For external input data, hash function must be "universal", i.e. resist to attempt generate collision.

My favorite hash function is following. Before 1st use, needed initialize the table S_block with some random values. Good idea to do it at each program run.

```
const unsigned int S_block[256] = { ... };
#define NLF(h, c) (S_block[(unsigned char)(c + h)] ^ c)

unsigned int hash(const char *key) {
unsigned int h = 0x1F351F35;
char c;
while(c = *key++)
  h = ((h << 7) | (h >> (32 - 7))) + NLF(h, c);
h ^= h >> 16;
return h ^ (h >> 8);
}
```

As practical example, see using variation of this function in the my program [emcSSH](https://github.com/Emercoin/emcssh). The file [htable.c](https://github.com/Emercoin/emcssh/blob/master/source/htable.c) contains variation of this function, suitable for the [double hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) algorithm.